# How do I hide a static block on one of my category product pages?

Tags: static-block

On all my product pages just below the main product images I have a static block called "block_product_img_bottom", which contains a small image.

All but one category must display this image, so how do I hide this static block on just one of my categories?

Comment: Which version of Magento do you have?

Comment: Hi @Andrea, I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.3.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2069932/3763649) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676622/removing-a-static-block-from-a-specific-page-xml-update), may help you

Comment: @Andrea Thank you for the links but I still haven't solved it. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go to the specific category page in the Magento backend, then look custom design and there for XML Layout update.

Then there you put that code

```
<reference name="product.info">
   <remove name="block_product_img_bottom"/>
</reference>
```

That´s it already.

**Update**
Try product.info instead of content. See code above.
Also I realized when looking at your website that its for a specific product. So please open the product then click on design and add the code there under Custom Layout Update

Comment: in the Magento backend: admin/catalog_category/my_category in Custom Design it doesn't show an XML Layout update box? It does say Custom Layout Update though, so I added your code in there but it shows no change to the front end. I have all caches disabled.
I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.3.

Comment: Here is a link to the live [website](http://switchlive.co.uk/index.php/led-lighting-products/led-accessories/emergency-maintained-module.html).

I just want to be able to hide the image (it looks like 3 images) shown below the product thumbnail. 

Any idea?

Comment: I have updated the code above

Comment: thank you, unfortunately I can't get this to work with the updated code. 

Do you think this is the best method for hiding a block on a product page or am I going about this the wrong way?

I just need to remove this block from a few pages, it needs to show on all the other product pages.

Comment: See my update above please

Comment: I have done as you instructed, but do I need to change the drop down buttons such as Custom Design or Page Layout?

Comment: no that should be alright like that.

Comment: well i'm stuck as it doesn't seem to want to work. Thank you for your help though. Much appreciated.

Comment: You should check in which block your static block gets called and use this as the reference name. I assumed its product.info but it could be something else.

Comment: ok i will keep trying.

Comment: so I just turned on the 'block hints' and it shows that the image I want removed, is not shown as being in a block at all.

But it is definitely inside a block (that I added via Admin) that has the identifier "block_product_img_bottom", I can turn it on and off. Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44628/discussion-between-klettseb-and-j-granty).

Comment: I finally solved the issue. 
In the local.xml file I found "container_product_image_1", when added to our earlier code - it did the trick! see below:

<reference name="product.info">
    <remove name="container_product_image_1"/>
</reference>

So your assistance did help me out - Thanks again. 
Now on to the next task =)